# Passing bundle from ListView to Adapter, Android

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have a listview of locations, from which I want users to select from.

After they select an item, I want the app to return specific entries based on that location..because I want to display a set of information in the ListView, I am using an Adapter; in the Result List, I am setting up to pass the array as a bundle:

```
//when listItem is clicked
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        //in checked, in listview get Item positions for checked items
        SparseBooleanArray checked = l.getCheckedItemPositions();

        //assign selected items to new String ArrayList
        List<String> selectedItem = new ArrayList<String>();


        //determine size of items checked (number)
        for (int i = 0; i < checked.size(); i++) {
            // Item position in adapter
            position = checked.keyAt(i);
            // Add location if it is checked i.e.) == TRUE!
            if (checked.valueAt(i))
                //add selected items to madapter
                selectedItem.add(madapter.getItem(position));
        }

        //create string output array, store new string array with selected items
        String[] outputStrArr = new String[selectedItem.size()];

        for (int i = 0; i < selectedItem.size(); i++) {
            outputStrArr[i] = selectedItem.get(i);
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                CustomMidwifeAdapter.class);

        // Create a bundle object
        Bundle b = new Bundle();


        b.putStringArray("selectedItems", outputStrArr);

        // Add the bundle to the intent.
        intent.putExtras(b);

        Intent intentstart = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                MidwifeResultList.class);



        // start the ResultActivity
        startActivity(intentstart);


    }
```

As you can see, my instincts are to pass the data to the adapter because that is where I am querying the Parse data:

```
public class CustomMidwifeAdapter extends ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject> {



      public static final String TAG = CustomMidwifeAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

        protected Context mContext;
        protected List<ParseUser> mUsers;
        protected ParseRelation<ParseObject> mMidwiferyfirm;
        protected ParseUser mCurentUser;

        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();

        //store selected items in array
        String[] resultArr = b.getStringArray("selectedItems");




        public CustomMidwifeAdapter(Context context)    {
            super(context, new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseObject>() {
                public ParseQuery create() {

                    // Here we can configure a ParseQuery to display
                    // midwives
                    ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("midwifefirm");
                    query.whereEqualTo("userType", "midwife");

                    return query;
                }
            });
        }
```

However, I am getting an error, cannot resolve method getIntent...I am thinking this is because I am not able to use it unless within an Activity..I could pass it to my ListActivity, but then I am not sure how to use it in my ParseQuery.

I've looked around for answers, and there was some reference to needing to use the context, but not sure if that applied to my problem.

Here is my MidwifeListActivity

```
public class MidwifeResultList extends ListActivity {


    public static final String TAG = MidwifeResultList.class.getSimpleName();

    private ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject> mainAdapter;

    protected ParseRelation<ParseUser> mPatientRelation;
    protected ParseUser mCurrentUser;



    protected List<ParseObject> mMidwife;

    private CustomMidwifeAdapter midwifeListAdapter;

    //calls Adapter; Adapter manages data model
    //adapts it to individual entries in widget
    //inflates, assigns it to rows
    ArrayAdapter<String> madapter;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);


        //initialize main ParseQueryAdapter
        mainAdapter = new CustomMidwifeAdapter(this);

        //which keys in Midwife object
        mainAdapter.setTextKey("practicename");
        mainAdapter.setTextKey("education");
        mainAdapter.setTextKey("yearsinpractice");
        mainAdapter.setTextKey("practicephilosophy");


        mCurrentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
        mPatientRelation = mCurrentUser.getRelation(ParseConstants.KEY_PATIENT_RELATION);


        setListAdapter(mainAdapter);
        mainAdapter.loadObjects();




    }


    protected void onListItemClick (ListView l, View v, int position, long id)  {

        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);


      if (getListView().isItemChecked(position)) {





          mCurrentUser.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
              @Override


              public void done(ParseException e) {

                  if (e != null) {

                      Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                  }

              }
          });

          Intent intent = new Intent(this, SelectedMidwife.class);
          intent.putExtra("practicename", "practicename");
          startActivity(intent);

      }

        else {
          //remove friend

      }




    }

}
```

Comment: You will definitely need to do it in your `MidwifeResultList` Activity, please post the code.

Comment: @DanielNugent I added it; if there was a way I could limit the query within this, that would work..or somehow pass it to the adapter from the list, so I can use it in the ParseQuery...

Comment: You have a couple of options here.  You can either pass the information as a bundle to your new activity OR just get the objectId of the item the user clicked on pass that as a string extra and create a new query on your next activity to search for that objectId and show it.  I'd go with the second option (i've had to do the same thing).

Comment: @JamesJones I did not think of the second option, but that does sound best.  I'll post the code once I get it figured out.

Comment: @MichaelCabus If you figure it out, be sure to post it as an answer, and accept your own answer!

Comment: No problem, hopefully it gets you what it needs, if not let me know.  Good luck!

Comment: @JamesJones just thinking this through..if I get the objectID, I still have to pass it to the new activity, but the adapter is where my ParseQuery is...would I still have to then pass it from Activity to Adapter?

Comment: Depends on if your next activity is using the same adapter.  I assumed it would be a different adapter or xml because you were going to provide more information.  Also is your next activity a list activity?  I suggested just passing the objectID and reusing it because from my personal experience it was a little bit easier to debug, but will be dependent on your app.  Also, you could just run another query in your new activity.

Comment: @JamesJones it is a different adapter; the next activity is a list activity..so I can run my ParseQuery in the ListActivity?

Comment: Yup, you should be able to and just set texts or whatever you want to set by getting the info directly from the query.  You'll only have one row as well since you will be searching by the objectId.  Let me know if you need sample code that i've used in the past.

Comment: @JamesJones sample code is always appreciated...but if not, that makes sense